# How to see who modified global credentials in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins server with multiple users that are able to create and modify Global credentials. Is there any way I can audit and see who did what with the credentials - who modified them, who added new creds, etc. Preferably, presented in  nice way similar to Job Config History plugin. Thanks

Comment: Why not use the JobConfigHistory plugin?

Comment: it doesn't show the Credentials changes... only job changes (or at least I cannot find where)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question a few days ago. You can use the [Audit Trail Plugin (GitHub)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/audit-trail-plugin) to audit changes to credentials. It logs the HTTP requests that modify credentials. However, it doesn't have a "config history"-style visualisation.

(Soon, it may also be able to log what jobs access the credentials)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the Job Configuration History Plugin.

Link should be something like:

https://your.jenkins.url/jobConfigHistory/history?name=credentials

What I noticed is that all changes are shown as if they were been done by 'System' - though they all were done by a specific user.